# Are these valid disadvantages of a REST-ful API?

Tags: rest

I get the basic idea of REST-ful API, but I can see how they're not ideal. I want to know where I'm wrong on the following assumptions.

**REST-ful API unnecessarily exposes models**

On a REST-ful API, it's usually a set of actions e.g CRUD on an entity. Sometimes performing a business action requires many models to be manipulated, and not just one.

For example, consider a business action of refunding an order, which then decreases a buyer's rating. Several possible models are involved here e.g Order, OrderItem, Payment, Buyer, Refund.

We often end up exposing single 'parent' model with an action that updates itself and its sub-models, or we end up exposing many models that must be updated appropriately to successfully accomplish the business action as a whole.

**REST-ful API forces one to think in terms of manipulating models instead of the natural behavior of stating intent**

Consider a customer service rating application. A customer can state his / her happiness once a support call ends e.g "I'm satisfied" / "I'm angry" / "I'm neutral".

In a REST-ful API, the customer has to figure out what exact model to manipulate in order to state how he feels. Perhaps a CustomerResponse model, or a Feedback model. Why can't the customer just hit an endpoint, identify himself and simply state whether he's happy or not, without having to know the underlying model that tracks his response?

**REST-ful API Update action oversimplifies too much**

Sometimes on a model, you want to do more than just an update. An update can be many things.

Consider a Word model. You can reverse the characters, randomize the characters, uppercase / lowercase the characters, split the word and many other actions that actually means a Word model is 'updated' in a certain way.

At this point, exposing just an Update action on Word probably oversimplifies how rich the Word model can be.

Comment: Why do you tend to tie DB model with REST? They can be completely separated.

Comment: It doesn't have to be DB models, but they're just models. In some ways, you still have to structure information / data. Some structure would be on its own, some would have sub-structures. The structures then would have responsibilities of their own. Given a business action that potentially involves manipulating a lot of structures - how would a REST-ful API expose this? That was the question.

Comment: Agree about the above disadvantages - REST exposes implementation details in a low-level and crude CRUD-fashion, and does *not* communicate the high-level intent. (It can also lock you in prematurely on an early implementation). I Would like to add two disadvantages. Performance: The low-level nature of REST can lead to more traffic than needed with higher-level actions. Traceability: Much more difficult to see the intention hidden in a sea of anonymous CRUD-style calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe the points you state above are really drawbacks of a RESTful API. More analytically:

**REST-ful API unnecessarily exposes models**

No models are exposed. Everything is handled by a single controller. The only thing that is exposed to the user is the route of the appropriate controller.

**REST-ful API forces one to think in terms of manipulating models instead of the natural behavior of stating intent**

Same as above. A single controller can handle the different customer happiness states. The distinction can be made by passing different post paramenters (ex. { state: "happy"}).

**REST-ful API Update action oversimplifies too much**

Nothing stops you from manipulating the data that needs to be sent to your model before updating it. You can do whatever you want, however complex it may be, before updating your model.

Finally, I believe that a RESTful API is only as good as its implementation. Furthermore, I believe that if you wanted to find a flaw to the REST technique is the fact that you cannot initiate transactions or push notifications server-side

Comment: But the controller ideally controls a resource, which to me is still model-ish. So in the refund case, we then need to figure out the overarching model that best encapsulates all the affected sub-models, and expose a 'Refund' route on it? Or should it be just a generically named 'Update' route, to keep in line with CRUD conventions? The latter however would not show the intent clearly IMHO.

Comment: you could have a general controller routed to 'user/transactions' for example, that handles all the user transactions depending on the posted transaction_type, ex. {transaction_type: "refund"}

Comment: Can I say then that controller = services, and routes = service methods / requests / messages? I  think this helps me understand it much better, without having to always tie it down back to a resource / model.

Answer (score 1):

First, Web service APIs that adhere to the REST architectural constraints are called RESTful APIs. HTTP based RESTful APIs are defined with these aspects:

- base URI, such as `http://example.com/resources/`
- an Internet media type for the data. This is often JSON but can be any other valid Internet media type (e.g. XML, Atom, microformats, images, etc.)
- standard HTTP methods (e.g., GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE)
- hypertext links to reference state
- hypertext links to reference related resources

**Now with your questions:**

> REST-ful API unnecessarily exposes models

In your example, if you want to refund someone, you obviously use more than one model.

RESTful doesn't means that you expose only one model, for example, a `POST` on a `/api/refunds` is a RESTful way of doing it without expose a single model.

The only thing peole see from you API are **routes to your different actions in your different controllers**

> REST-ful API forces one to think in terms of manipulating models instead of the natural behavior of stating intent

Your RESTful API is called from a front-end (smartphone app, javascript app, etc..) or a back-end (a server), the end user (here, the satisfied/angry/neutral client) is not obligated to see the url called by your front-end, the satisfaction form could be here `/support/survey` and the **server API url** could be a `POST` to `/api/support_calls/1/surveys`.

> REST-ful API Update action oversimplifies too much

An `PUT` on a RESTful route does **NOT** means that you should only update one model. You can manipulate params, create a model, update another, and then, update your main model.

**Finally**

Dont forget that RESTful architecture is a **ROUTE** and **URL** architecture created for **developpers**, you can do anything you want in your controllers, this is just a **convention-based way of exposing your URLs** to API's consumers

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to address your concerns, but keep in mind that the topic is very mch debatable, so take this as my humble opinion..

1) about the model being unnecessary exposed, well I think it is mostly a matter of modeling your domain entities in a way that allows you to express all the available action and concepts in terms of 'doing something on a resource'. In the refund example, you could for instance model a `Refund` entity and perform actions on that.

2) here too is a matter of modeling domain entities and services. Your happiness service could be a matter of having a service accepting a user id and an integer expressing the user's satissfaction level.

3) In the case of the Word model, you can simply use the PATCH (or PUT) http verb and provide a service that simply overwrites the resource, which would in turn be manipulated by the client.

Again, REST is a paradigm, so it is (among other things) a way to organize the objects of your domain and the actions that can be performed on those objects. Obviously it has drawbacks and limitations, but I personally think that it is quite 'transparent' (i.e. not imposing artificial constraints on your programming), and that it is quite easy to use, being mostly based on widely accepted conventions and technologies (i.e. http verbs and so on).